# Summing data for previous month

Tags: sql

I am having trouble summing up the data for a previous month.  Here is what I have so far

```
SELECT 
    Coalesce(Sum(LIN_PROD_RATE), 0) 
FROM 
    Stafford Totals 
WHERE 
    MONTH(t_stamp) = MONTH(DATEADD(month, -1, current_timestamp))
```

Any ideas???

Comment: Please be more specific on what tables you have and what data you want to get summed up.

Comment: What is wrong with the query you have?

Comment: seems like you want to make sure the month = month.  maybe wrap the DATEADD function with the MONTH like this:  MONTH( DATEADD( month, -1...)

Comment: What database?  MS, MySQL, Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

```
select coalesce(sum(LIN_PROD_RATE), 0)
from Stafford
where
  t_stamp >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, current_timestamp)-1, 0) and
  t_stamp < dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, current_timestamp), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @last_month as datetime;
set @last_month = DATEADD(month, -1, getdate());

SELECT 
    Coalesce(Sum(LIN_PROD_RATE), 0) 
FROM 
    Stafford Totals 
WHERE 
    MONTH(t_stamp) = MONTH(@last_month)
    AND YEAR(t_stamp) = YEAR(@last_month)
```

Comment: +1. (Of course, to be completely correct (including midnight on new year's eve) you would want to `declare @reference_timestamp` and `set @reference_timestamp = current_timestamp`, etc.)

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi - There were two references to current_timestamp in the original query. If they resolved to two different dates, then the month and year combination that resulted would be wrong. This is very unlikely to happen in practice, but as a matter of mathematical and logical correctness, the same timestamp must be used throughout the query.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi - I don't see where the OP says they are using SQL Server. Also, I can find no API documentation that states that the functions are defined to operate that way. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Jeffrey / The combination of DateAdd, Current_Timestamp, Month() only work in SQL Server, AFAIK. You're right about current_timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If it were MySQL:

```
select coalesce(sum(lin_prod_rate), 0) 
from stafford totals 
where date_format(t_stamp, '%Y-%m') = date_format(date_add(curdate(), interval -1 month), '%Y-%m')
```